Generic method signature at ILLink.Substitutions.xml
I'm using ILLink.Substitutions.xml to create a assembly library trimmable.
This would be example code.
namespace NSpace;

public static class NClass 
{
    public static void NGenericMethod<TGeneric>(Boolean condition1, Boolean condition2, TGeneric value, String name) where TGeneric : unmanaged, IEqualityOperators<TGeneric, TGeneric, Boolean> {
        // Body
    }
}

This would be ILLink.Substitutions.xml example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="NAssembly">
        <type fullname="NSpace.NClass" feature="NAssembly.EnableFeature" featurevalue="false">
            <method signature="System.Void NGenericMethod`1(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,!0,System.String)" body="stub"\>
        </type>
    </assembly>
</linker>

But I'm getting warning IL2009: Could not find method 'System.Void NGenericMethod`1(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,!0,System.String)' on type 'NClass.NClass'.
I expect get no warning and method body substitution.

Open your assembly in a tool like ILSpy or ILdasm - do the full-names and method signatures match exactly?

This xml file is invalid, it's extremely messy.

Moreover, the warning shows the type you specified is NClass.NClass, the class defination is missing the class keyword.

Errors in code/xml are typo.

@Dai In ILSpy method signature was something like
NGenericMethod``1< TGeneric >(bool, bool, TGeneric, string) : void
Of course using System types I let it as:
System.Void NGenericMethod``1(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,TGeneric,System.String)
But it doesn't work.

Apparently the signature of the generic method with the parameter should be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="NAssembly">
        <type fullname="NSpace.NClass" feature="NAssembly.EnableFeature" featurevalue="false">
            <method signature="System.Void NGenericMethod`1(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,,System.String)" body="stub"\>
        </type>
    </assembly>
</linker>

